# Cucumber with Java Selenium framework

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, cucumber

I am working as a manual tester now recently I shifted to Selenium, in my company now they are telling me to create Cucumber Java Selenium framework for a project from scratch. My requirement is I need to create a class which it consists of all the methods of selenium like, sendKeys, Click, dragAndDrop, mouseHover like that all selenium related actions I need to put in one class...I'm facing very difficulty.

Does anyone have such type of class which has all Selenium actions?

Comment: While putting problem statement you should have shared what have you tried and achieved so far not by just saying in lines rather piece of code you wrote.

Comment: check this out : https://github.com/far11ven/Selenium-CucumberJUnitFramework

Comment: ALSO, http://elisarver.com/2012/12/09/wrapping-webelement-1/

Comment: and http://elisarver.com/2012/12/10/wrapping-webelement-2/

Comment: In general, the roles of manual tester and developer-in-test are substantially different, and asking one to do the role of the other is asking for trouble. The task of building Cucumber-to-Selenium frameworks (tailored to the specific needs of your organisation) needs a developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use webdriver methods like the following. For the full list please check https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/method_list.html

```
get()
getCurrentUrl()
findElement(By, by) and click()
isEnabled()
findElement(By, by) with sendKeys()
findElement(By, by) with getText()
Submit()
findElements(By, by)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a class with all of those actions; Selenium provides them out of the box. This can be achieved simply by instantiating a new instance of the driver:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And then calling the functions you require:

```
driver.getElement(By.id("element")).click();
```

Creating a new class to wrap an existing function is terrible *terrible* practice. If you're looking for a good design pattern for Selenium tests, look up the 'Page Object Model'.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this methods will be helpful to you

```
public static void wait(int secs) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * secs);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }


        /**
         * Generates the String path to the screenshot taken.
         * Within the method, the screenshot is taken and is saved into FileUtils.
         * The String return will have a unique name destination of the screenshot itself.
         *
         * @param name Test name passed in as a String
         * @return unique String representation of the file's location / path to file
         */
        public static String getScreenshot(String name) {
            // name the screenshot with the current date time to avoid duplicate name
            //for windows users or if you cannot get a screenshot
            String date = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy_MMdd_hh_mm_ss_a"));
            // TakesScreenshot ---> interface from selenium which takes screenshots
            TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) Driver.getDriver();
            File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            // full path to the screenshot location
            String target = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/Screenshots/" + name + date + ".png";
            //if screenshot doesn't work
            //try to provide hardcoded path
    //        String target = "/Users/studio2/IdeaProjects/Spring2019FinalTestNGFramework/screenshots/" + name + date + ".png";

            File finalDestination = new File(target);

            // save the screenshot to the path given
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return target;
        }


        /*
         * switches to new window by the exact title
         * returns to original window if windows with given title not found
         */
        public static void switchToWindow(String targetTitle) {
            String origin = Driver.getDriver().getWindowHandle();
            for (String handle : Driver.getDriver().getWindowHandles()) {
                Driver.getDriver().switchTo().window(handle);
                if (Driver.getDriver().getTitle().equals(targetTitle)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            Driver.getDriver().switchTo().window(origin);
        }

        public static void hover(WebElement element) {
            Actions actions = new Actions(Driver.getDriver());
            actions.moveToElement(element).perform();
        }

        /**
         * return a list of string from a list of elements
         * text
         *
         * @param list of webelements
         * @return
         */
        public static List<String> getElementsText(List<WebElement> list) {
            List<String> elemTexts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (WebElement el : list) {
                if (!el.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    elemTexts.add(el.getText());
                }
            }
            return elemTexts;
        }


        /**
         * Extracts text from list of elements matching the provided locator into new List<String>
         *
         * @param locator
         * @return list of strings
         */
        public static List<String> getElementsText(By locator) {
            List<WebElement> elems = Driver.getDriver().findElements(locator);
            List<String> elemTexts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (WebElement el : elems) {
                if (!el.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    elemTexts.add(el.getText());
                }
            }
            return elemTexts;
        }

        public static WebElement waitForVisibility(WebElement element, int timeToWaitInSec) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), timeToWaitInSec);
            return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        }

        public static WebElement waitForVisibility(By locator, int timeout) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), timeout);
            return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        }

        public static WebElement waitForClickability(WebElement element, int timeout) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), timeout);
            return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        }

        public static WebElement waitForClickability(By locator, int timeout) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), timeout);
            return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
        }

        public static Boolean waitForURL(String actualURL, int timeout) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), 5);
            return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe(actualURL));
        }

        public static void waitForPageToLoad(long timeOutInSeconds) {
            ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
                }
            };
            try {
                Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UtilsBrowser.class);
                logger.info("Waiting for page to load...");
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), timeOutInSeconds);
                wait.until(expectation);
            } catch (Throwable error) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete after " + timeOutInSeconds + " seconds");
            }
        }

        public static WebElement fluentWait(final WebElement webElement, int timeinsec) {
            FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(Driver.getDriver())
                    .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeinsec))
                    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
            WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return webElement;
                }
            });
            return element;
        }

        /**
         * Verifies whether the element matching the provided locator is displayed on page
         *
         * @param by
         * @throws AssertionError if the element matching the provided locator is not found or not displayed
         */
        public static void verifyElementDisplayed(By by) {
            try {
                assertTrue("Element not visible: " + by, Driver.getDriver().findElement(by).isDisplayed());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Assert.fail("Element not found: " + by);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Verifies whether the element matching the provided locator is NOT displayed on page
         *
         * @param by
         * @throws AssertionError the element matching the provided locator is displayed
         */
        public static void verifyElementNotDisplayed(By by) {
            try {
                Assert.assertFalse("Element should not be visible: " + by, Driver.getDriver().findElement(by).isDisplayed());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Verifies whether the element is displayed on page
         *
         * @param element
         * @throws AssertionError if the element is not found or not displayed
         */
        public static void verifyElementDisplayed(WebElement element) {
            try {
                assertTrue("Element not visible: " + element, element.isDisplayed());
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Assert.fail("Element not found: " + element);
            }
        }


        /**
         * Waits for element to be not stale
         *
         * @param element
         */
        public void waitForStaleElement(WebElement element) {
            int y = 0;
            while (y <= 15) {
                if (y == 1)
                    try {
                        element.isDisplayed();
                        break;
                    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException st) {
                        y++;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (WebDriverException we) {
                        y++;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Selects a random value from a dropdown list and returns the selected Web Element
         *
         * @param select
         * @return
         */
        public static WebElement selectRandomTextFromDropdown(Select select) {
            Random random = new Random();
            List<WebElement> weblist = select.getOptions();
            int optionIndex = 1 + random.nextInt(weblist.size() - 1);
            select.selectByIndex(optionIndex);
            return select.getFirstSelectedOption();
        }

        /**
         * Clicks on an element using JavaScript
         *
         * @param element
         */
        public void clickWithJS(WebElement element) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
            ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
        }


        /**
         * Scrolls down to an element using JavaScript
         *
         * @param element
         */
        public void scrollToElement(WebElement element) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        }

        /**
         * Performs double click action on an element
         *
         * @param element
         */
        public void doubleClick(WebElement element) {
            new Actions(Driver.getDriver()).doubleClick(element).build().perform();
        }

        /**
         * Changes the HTML attribute of a Web Element to the given value using JavaScript
         *
         * @param element
         * @param attributeName
         * @param attributeValue
         */
        public void setAttribute(WebElement element, String attributeName, String attributeValue) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2]);", element, attributeName, attributeValue);
        }

        public String[] fromListToString(List<WebElement> x) {
            String[] trans = new String[x.size()];
            for (WebElement xx : x) {
                int count = 0;
                trans[count] = xx.getText();
                count++;
            }
            Arrays.sort(trans);
            return trans;
        }

        /**
         * Highlighs an element by changing its background and border color
         *
         * @param element
         */
        public static void highlight(WebElement element) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", element);
            wait(1);
            ((JavascriptExecutor) Driver.getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", element);
        }

        /**
         * Checks or unchecks given checkbox
         *
         * @param element
         * @param check
         */
        public static void selectCheckBox(WebElement element, boolean check) {
            if (check) {
                if (!element.isSelected()) {
                    element.click();
                }
            } else {
                if (element.isSelected()) {
                    element.click();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void grabHold(WebDriver driver) {
            /* /NOTE: Be sure to set -> String parentHandle=driver.getWindowHandle(); prior to the action preceding method deployment */
            String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
            Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
            for (String window : windows) {
                if (window != parentHandle)
                    driver.switchTo().window(window);
            }
        }

        public static void waitUntilTitleEquals(int timeout, String x) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), timeout);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(x));
        }


        public static int getRandomNumInRange(int low, int high) {
            Random random = new Random();
            return random.nextInt(high - low) + low;
        }


        public void waitForPresenceOfElementByCss(String css) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(),
                    Long.parseLong(ConfigurationReader.getProperties("timeout")));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(css)));
        }


        public void hitEnterUsingRobot() {
            Robot rb;
            try {
                rb = new Robot();
                rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }


        public boolean verifyAlertPresent() {
            try {
                Driver.getDriver().switchTo().alert();
                return true;
            } catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) {
    //            System.out.println("Alert is not presenet");
            }
            return false;
        }

        public boolean isElementVisible(By arg0) {
            boolean elementVisible = false;
            try {
                (new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), 60)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(arg0));
                elementVisible = true;

            } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
                elementVisible = false;
            }
            return elementVisible;
        }

        public static boolean isElementNotVisible(By arg0) {
            boolean elementVisible = false;
            try {
                //these two waitinf for webelement to be gone
    //            (new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), 60)).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(arg0));
                (new WebDriverWait(Driver.getDriver(), 60)).until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(arg0)));
                elementVisible = true;
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                elementVisible = false;
            }
            return elementVisible;
        }
```